# What are the reasons that its decision to open itself automatically or not is based on?

Tags: grammar, phrases

Is the following phrase grammatically right?
"When Twitter shows a notification, what are the reasons that its decision to open itself automatically or not is based on?"

This question is probably banal to most of you, but I'm Italian and I think this phrase has something strange, isn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sentence has a lot of embedding.  We can make better sense of it by abstracting out one or more complex parts of the sentence.  I have put brackets around one complex phrase that forms a single unit:

> What are the reasons that [its decision to open itself automatically or not] is based on?

This could be abstracted to:

> What are the reasons that X is based on?

The above sentence could be put another way to be clearer, but have essentially the same meaning:

> What reasons is X based on?

As you can see, the sentence is grammatical and parse-able.  However, you are right in thinking it is an awkward sentence; it is written in a confusing way, even for native speakers.

Comment: Or perhaps even a bit more simply, "Why is [X]?".

Answer (score 2):

The phrase is clumsy and unclear, but I wouldn't say it's actually incorrect. A better rendering might be:

> What are the factors that Twitter takes into account when deciding whether to open itself automatically on showing a notification?

Comment: Yep, I did reformulated it in the same way. +1